# Can I enable the tomcat manager app for Spring Boot's embedded tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I'm doing a research project to determine to what extent we can configure embedded Tomcat with Spring boot. One of the items I was asked to look into was with regard to whether we can still use the app manager. I don't have a specific use case for why we'd want to use an app manager with an embedded tomcat, so maybe that makes this question unanswerable:

Does the embedded tomcat 7 used by Spring Boot contain a tomcat manager app, and if not, what does it take to add/enable it?

Comment: What's your use case for the manager app? Without knowing that, it's hard to say whether or not it makes sense.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, unfortunately I don't have one. I edited my question to explain.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, the tomcat manager used to be quite useful for me to know which user is logged in and his time of inactivity. AFAIK Spring Boot provides endpoints only for active session count and max session count.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Does the embedded tomcat 7 used by Spring Boot contain a tomcat manager app

No, it doesn't and I'm not really sure that it makes sense to try to add it.

A primary function of the manager app is to allow you to start and stop individual applications without stopping the container and to deploy and undeploy individual applications. When you're using Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat you should consider your application and container as a single entity so starting or stopping your application and starting and stopping the container are one and the same thing.

A secondary function of the manager app is to provide access to OS and JVM properties, something that Spring Boot's actuator already does for you.

> What does it take to add/enable it?

If you choose not to heed the above, it's easy to add the manager app (although I can't promise that it all works as expected – I leave that as an exercise for the (foolhardy) reader):

```java
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.addUser("admin", "secret");
            tomcat.addRole("admin", "manager-gui");

            try {
                tomcat.addWebapp("/manager", "/path/to/manager/app");
            }
            catch (ServletException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add manager app", ex);
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}
```

You'll also need a dependency on Jasper as the manager app uses JSPs. Assuming you're using Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, Answers the question well, However it begs the question... I assume there is no way then to avoid the 20+ odd second wait each time I "rerun" the application with springboot?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way how to [convert Spring Boot's JAR to WAR](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/). After that you can use your hosted tomcat manager.

You need to say to Maven/Gradle to cuild WAR instead of JAR and create this basic servet configuration

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class HelloWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to know if it's possible to do this with tomcat embedded in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a list of endpoints, you could configure your application to generate swagger pages.
I use spring boot and springfox.

**API Docs:**
http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

**Swagger UI:**
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

**Tutorial:**
[Springfox Reference Documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/)

#### Code:

```
package some.package;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.paths.RelativePathProvider;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${swagger.host:}")
    private String swaggerHost;

    @Value("${swagger.basePath:/}")
    private String swaggerBasePath;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host(swaggerHost)
            .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
                @Override
                public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                    return swaggerBasePath;
                }
            })
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("path.to.package"))
            .build();
    }
}
```