# TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Authentication required dialog box

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm  trying to access the Spring Boot appication running on embedded Tomcat container on the local machine using `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/`

As I access the application the dialouge box is being displayed.

For a non-embedded Tomcact container I can modify the tomcat-server.xml and add

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

How would I do it on embedded tomcat container?

Comment: May be your embedded tomcat is configured to use ""basic authentication",

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995635/can-i-enable-the-tomcat-manager-app-for-spring-boots-embedded-tomcat/25999919#25999919 where there is an example of configuring users programmatically

Comment: pom.xml had Spring Security dependency definition. Spring Boot has auto configured the security, once the dependency is removed the app worked fine. After configuring the security, the dialouge has not shown up. Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [addUser()/addRole() methods](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html#addUser%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).