# Getting Spring Session information from Spring Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session, spring-data-redis, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring cloud based application that stores the spring session in redis. It is using Spring Boot with embedded tomcat.

When using spring actuator, the /metrics endpoint does not return any valuable information. httpsessions.active is set to 0, and httpsessions.max is set to -1.

I am guessing this is because spring replaces the httpsession implementation with its own spring session implementation.

Is there a way to access this information from some endpoint? preferably using JMX but not mandatory.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the only [workaround I have found](https://moelholm.com/2016/08/22/spring-boot-sessions-actuator-endpoint/). Would be good for spring boot actuator to implement this kind of functionality, since it seems to be [no easy way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995635/can-i-enable-the-tomcat-manager-app-for-spring-boots-embedded-tomcat) to enable the tomcat manager in a spring boot app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually used the following solution, by using a generic username. The endpoint would return all sessions, a simple count would give the total.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/findbyusername.html

Comment: Please provide the solution at the body of your answer. The link you provided is broken.