# Web Application Manager for Spring Boot MVC jar - display all jars

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am quite new to Spring boot and I have just created a small spring boot mvc web application as a jar.

1. Is there some kind of `Web Application Manager` like with Tomcat, where one can stop or undeploy/delete?
2. Or do I have to manually upload the jar to my server and manually type in the console `java -jar myFile.jar`?
3. How do I stop/restart my jar web application?
4. How do I display/list all my active running jar web applications?

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This post may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995635/can-i-enable-the-tomcat-manager-app-for-spring-boots-embedded-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there some kind of Web Application Manager like with Tomcat, where one can stop or undeploy/delete?

   - Nope. There isn't and you actually don't need one. As mentioned in comment by Shankar [do read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995635/can-i-enable-the-tomcat-manager-app-for-spring-boots-embedded-tomcat).
2. Or do I have to manually upload the jar to my server and manually type in the console java -jar myFile.jar?

   - You don't upload you `myFile.jar` application to tomcat, spring-boot has embedded Tomcat server. When you run `java -jar myFile.jar` sringboot apliication starts this embedded tomcat server and runs your application in it.
3. How do I stop/restart my jar web application?

   - You can simply kill the `java -jar myFile.jar` process by pressing `Ctlr + C`.
4. How do I display/list all my active running jar web applications?

   - Each Springboot application has its own embedded tomcat server, so this is N/A.

> Now if you want to deploy your spring boot application in standalone Tomcat server where you can see the GUI, app manager, start/stop etc. create a **WAR** file instead of **JAR**.
>
> Read this [Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) on converting jar-to-war.
>   In short, creating a WAR file answers all your questions.