# Does spring need to be restarted to reload keystore and truststore?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sslcontext

I see that the keystore is constructed on spring initialization and thus the application needs to be restarted if a new entry is added to the keystore. Does this also apply to the truststore?

Can I do a reload without restarting by creating a new SSLContext to use? Such as:

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslcontext.init((KeyManager[])null, (TrustManager[])null, (SecureRandom)null);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct, it does.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring throu Tomcat you could reload the ssl-truststore (`Re-read TLS configuration files`) by the tomcat-admin-layer.

[image]

See here how to activate the admin-panel: [Can I enable the tomcat manager app for Spring Boot's embedded tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995635)

Comment: Thanks! It also looks like hot reload is a feature in 3.2.0 https://spring.io/blog/2023/11/07/ssl-hot-reload-in-spring-boot-3-2-0